# Is + operator overloaded for primitive types?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Already overloaded operators <<,>>,= etc are used many times.

An example that i was thinking of is when we add strings say :

> string name = string("munish") + "kumar";

the + operator is overloaded in the string class.

but when we add numbers like 1 + 2( doesn't seem like an overloaded operator call)

I was just wondering how does it happens does the compiler does a binary additon.

I don't need to worry about it much though if the compiler does it so, just a matter of curiosity for me.

Comment: The code example is wrong, the types of the two arguments are *array of N characters*, and they will decay to *pointer to characters* that cannot be added. You probably meant: `std::string name = std::string("muhish") + "kumar";`

Comment: @David: Actually, the arrays won't decay to pointers, because simply speaking, array-to-pointer decay only happens "when it makes the compiler happy". For example, g++ says `invalid operands of types 'const char [7]' and 'const char [6]' to binary 'operator+'`. Note that the error message mentions arrays, not pointers.

Comment: @FredOverflow: right, if there was a function or operator that took a pointer, it would decay, if there was a function that took an array reference it would not... I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitive types don't implement `operator+` which is actually a function with a weird name. Addition for Primitive type is carried out by CPU instruction such as :

```
addl %edx,(%eax) //this adds two integral values loaded at edx and eax
```

You implement `operator+` for user-defined types, and compiler generates lots of CPU instructions to carry out the task which you write in `operator+`.

Comment: Nawaz so if I have an overlaoede operator+ say for adding two objects is defined then if a statment like 1+2 (int addtion/primitive dataytpe) won't be calling the overloaded operator but only when object addition is performed it wiil be called.Am I right

Comment: @munish: Yes. You define `operator+` for particular user-defined type; that `operator+` doesn't get called for integer additions; they're not called for *other* user-defined types also.

Comment: For the purposes of overload resolution, the compiler behaves "as if" there were functions `operator+(int, int)`, etc.  You can't define them, but that doesn't mean that they aren't conceptually there.

Comment: @James: I think, in that case, conceptual existence of `operator+(int,int)` would be conceptually different from `operator+(const A&, const A&)`.

Comment: @Nawaz At what level?  The compiler synthesizes the function signatures `operator(int, int)` for overload resolution; during overload resolution, they exist just as really as user defined overloads.  Once the compiler chooses one, it generates code for it; the `operator+(int, int)` will cause different code to be generated than `operator+(A const&, A const&)`.  But then, `operator+(int, int)` will also generate different code than `operator+(double, double)`.  I think that the differences are probably less than one imagines.

Comment: @Nawaz At any rate, your original answer is only valid for one specific machine (and compiler):-).  I've used machines where `operator+(float, float)` generated a function call.

Comment: @James: ish, I think it gets tricky with types below `int` and mismatched addition. I suppose you could also imagine an `int operator+(char, char)` that converts its arguments to int and adds them, although different C++ implementations define different "conceptual" overloads, depending on the relative widths of their integer types. Exciting! Plus, it means that when you discover C doesn't have function overloading, you have to re-learn it all in terms of built-in operators anyway...

Comment: @James: Can we see the  generated `operator+(int,int)`? Is there any compiler option which can show us such generated code?

Comment: @Nawaz: no you can't, the standard doesn't say it's there and there's no guarantee that's how the compiler actually does it. You can't for example take a pointer to it as you can to `std::operator+(const string&, const string&)`. James is just saying that *if you want to*, you can understand the usual arithmetic conversions as a set of operator overloads. To make that correct it might need to be a very long list of overloads to cover all the n^2 combinations of numeric types you can add together - personally I just use the the promotion/conversion rules.

Comment: @Steve: I understand that. But its also possible that the compiler directly generates machine instructions for arithmetics involving the primitive datatypes, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: sure. But then, it's also possible that the compiler directly generates machine instructions for adding two strings. Unlikely -- every C++ implementation I know defines strings like any other user-defined class template in a header file, and then inlines the function call or not according to its usual rules -- but legal. In principle there's no way of telling by examining the output, whether "James is right" and the compiler believes that it's inlining an `operator+(int,int)`, or "you're right" and the compiler believes it's just spitting out an opcode. They're equivalent.

Comment: And btw that's one of the reasons that it's UB for a program to add definitions to `namespace std` except in some limited cases. There's no way to predict how new definitions interact with any special magic that the compiler might use to resolve calls in there. That frees the implementation to use magic that relies on the only definitions being the standard ones it knows about. That said, I don't know if many implementations use that freedom.

Comment: @Steve: The last comment is simply awesome; you added it at right time, as the previous comments prepare the mind to be able to understand this comment you just made. :-)

Comment: Several points: first, one of the first things a compiler does in an
arithmetic expression is apply integral promotion, so there is no
`operator+(char, char)`.   There is an `operator+(int, long)`, however,
and all of the other possible combinations of promoted arithmetic types.
And second, I'm not saying "if you want to"; I'm simply summarizing what
the standard says, in §13.6.

Comment: @Nawaz with regards to "seeing" the generated `operator+(int, int)`: if you mean the C++ in the function body, no, since it is built-in (i.e. there is no C++ in the function body---the compiler knows what to do).  If you mean the generated code, most compilers have an option to output assembler.  But I'm not sure what that would show: I often overload `operator++` for an `enum` type, and the generated assembler is identical to that for `operator++(int&)`, even though one is built-in, and the other user defined.

Comment: @James: 13.6 says, "built-in operators take only operands with non-class type, and operator overload resolution occurs only when an operand expression originally has class or enumeration type". All those overloads are for dealing with arithmetic on user-defined types that have conversions to arithmetic types. Which isn't to say that the compiler *can't* use them internally to figure out `char+char` or `int+int`, but the standard doesn't say that it does. Arithmetic on builtin types is defined in the chapter on expressions, that's where promotion and conversions are specified to apply.

Comment: thanks Steve, guess there are no more doubts.+1 for bringing out article 13.6

Comment: @Steve Jessop The actual rules for overload resolution among the
built-in operators are described in §5, in order to be compatible with
C.  The overloads on the built-in types in §13.6 are designed such that
they will result in the same overload being chosen, but once chosen, it
is the rules in §5 which specify what happens.  Since the set of
overloads in §13.6 contains all legal combinations, it really doesn't
matter which way you read it; anything between built-in types will find
an exact match (although sending you back to §5 immediately is
probably better for reasons of C compatibility).

Comment: where do you find these rules(§13.6, §5) guys can i have a look at it or do you have a hard copy

Comment: @munish: the current standard is called "ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)", which you can search for. The current draft of the next standard is called n3290 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing two things: operator overloading, and how you
define an operator for a user defined type.  Operator overloading isn't
new; it exists already in C, where `+` is overloaded on `int`, `unsigned
int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `float`, `double` and `long double`.  In
C++, you can add operators for user defined types, by defining a
function named `operator+`, so the list of overloads is longer.  And to
make things more coherent, the way the compiler resolves the overload is
to add synthesized signatures along the lines of `operator+(int, int)`
to the list of overloads.  If the overload resolution then ends up
choosing one of these synthesized signatures, it uses the built-in
operator, generating whatever machine code is necessary (which may
involve a function call at the machine code level).  The fact that it
chooses one of the "build-in" overloads does have repercussions in the
rest of the code: a user defined operator is considered a function call,
with the corresponding sequence points and all of the rest, and the
compiler is not allowed to make any assumptions concerning its
semantics—in particular, the compiler cannot assume that a user
defined `operator+` is associative or commutative.  A build-in operator
(with a very few exceptions) does not introduce any sequence points, and
the compiler knows its semantics, and can optimize in consequence.

Note that the generated machine code may not be that different.  I've
used machines where the compiler had to call a function to multiply
`int`s, and the compiler can (and often will) inline a user defined
operator.  What changes is the rules I mentionned above: the presence of
sequence points in user defined operators, and the fact that the
compiler cannot make assumptions concerning the various mathematical
laws which might apply.

Comment: "Operator overloading isn't new; it exists already in C, where + is overloaded on int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, float, double and long double" @James are you saying that its already overlaoded in C++ too.

Comment: hmm i get it they are overlaoded.+1 (quite reasonable)

Comment: Are you saying that any compilers actually work this way internally? i.e. literally resolve arithmetic operators by deploying their function overload resolution mechanism, the synthesized functions perhaps having some tag to indicate to the optimizer that no sequence points are implied? What about C compilers that aren't C++ compilers and therefore wouldn't otherwise need a function overload resolution mechanism at all?

Comment: @Steve Jessop I've not actually looked at any sources for the overload
mechanism, but I don't really see any other reasonable way of handling
it in the presence of user defined overloads.  I imaging that's why the
standard introduces so many overloads: in order to ensure an exact
match, and avoid ambituity.  Without user defined overloads, of course,
the rules in §5 are easy to implement directly.

Comment: @James: what user-defined overloads? AFAIK you can't overload anything that would affect the meaning of `int+int`, so the rules in 5 can be implemented directly regardless. I don't really feel equipped to work out whether using all those overloads really is equivalent to the promotion/conversion rules, there are a lot of cases to consider.

Comment: @Steve Programs with no user defined overloads are rare, think of
`std::string`.  And when the overload resolution chooses a built-in
operator (regardless of how or why), it has to go back to §5 for the
semantics anyway.  The simplest solution is probably: if only built-in
types and pointers, as per §5, otherwise, as per §13.6, reverting to §5
for the semantics if the chosen overload is one of the built-ins.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the operators on custom data types i.e classes.. int is a primitive data type and the operators on primitive types are implemented by the compiler itself, basically it is just a simple CPU instruction to add int etc