# operator overloading example in C++

Tags: c++

i need a good simple example of operator overloading. without using class or struct. here i have tried but getting error:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int operator+(int a, int b)
{
  return a-b;
}

void main()
{
  int a,b,sum;
  cin>>a>>b;
  sum=a+b;  //Actually it will subtruct because of + operator overloading.
  cout<<"Sum of "<<a<<" & "<<b<<"(using overloading)"<<sum;
}
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Compiling OVERLOAD.CPP:
Error OVERLOAD.CPP 3: 'operator +(int,int)' must be a member function or have a parameter of class type
```

let me know is it possible to overload operator (sum=a+b) ? if yes then please do correction in my source.

Comment: As an aside, do you want to overload '+' do do (a-b)?

Comment: Make a wrapper class for your `int`, and overload the operator for that wrapper class. Ktodisco gives an example.

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++. Use `int main`.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to override operators on primitive types like ints. As the compiler states, at least one parameter's type must be a class.

Answer (score 4):

Operator overloading is for class types only.  Primitive type operators are not defined by a function.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211395/is-operator-overloaded-for-primitive-types) for details.

If you have a class type, you can overload the operator:

```
class A
{
    int _num;

public:
    A(int n) : _num(n) {}

    int operator+(const int b) const
    {
        return _num + b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a(2);
    int result = a + 4; // result = 6

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to override operators if both the operands are of primitive type. Compiler saying that atleast one operand should be object of a class.

```
class Demo{
   int n;
   Demo(int n){
      this.n = n;
   }
   int operator+(int a){
    return n + a;
   }
}


int main(){  
   Demo d(10);
   int result = d + 10; //See one operand is Object
   return 0;
}
```

When you are doing operator overloading using class member function, atleast first operand should be object. You cannot do `10 - d`. To do so you need to implement operator overloading using `friend` function.

```
  friend int operator-(int a, Demo d){
    return a - n;
  }
```

Comment: *"When you are doing operator overloading using normal function"* I suppose you mean "member function" or "instance method"; also, often `friend` is not needed, the term you want is "free function".